# finding subspac of $R^4$ vectors described by equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the dimension of the subspace of $R^4$ described with all vectors of the form
$( w , x , y , z )$ that satisfy $$− 3 x + z = 0 , x + y + 4 z − w = 0$$
put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} w \\ x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus the dimension is $2$.

Comment: ahh right i need to turn it into row echelon form and count first coefficients(donno what it called)